# Tiddlywiki: embed/link to .msg

Tags: outlook, tiddlywiki

I'd like to use Tiddlywiki for a personal knowledge base. In my work flow a lot of content comes in as Outlook emails threads.

Is there a smart way to refer to this content without fully copying over the whole text to each and every tiddler manually?

Maybe saving Outlook mail thread as .msg file, placing it locally and referring to that file might work. The tiddler then may hold some basic summy, but whole detail content lies in the .msg file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Managing email is horribly difficult and I don't think even TiddlyWiki can help.  I can only recommend careful and skilled use of Outlook.  For example, I alter emails by inserting keywords into the body or re-writing the subject line for better retrieval.  (Copying emails into project folders OUTSIDE Outlook only gets me into trouble!)  Sorry this is so far from answering your question, but that's my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I am in such case (more struggling with TiddlyWiki, which is great but lacks documentation currently). I ended up using the outlook:*oid* url-style that opens the mail in outlook. However, it's difficult to retrieve a mail oid, especially as this id changes when copying (and maybe moving) the mail to other folders/pst files.

In my case, I use some outlook mailbox parser that detect specific markup (categories, actions), and take appropriate actions (move them, create the outlook:oid link somewhere, etc). It's ugly but does the job.

Answer (score -1):

You've essentially answered your own question. Alternatively, use gmail or the likes to get proper links that only you can follow.